Flat minimal torus in a sphere
Suppose that a flat $n$-dimensional torus $T$ is isometrically embedded into the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^N$ of large dimension.
Furthermore, $T$ is a minimal submanifold in $\mathbb{S}^N$.

Is it true that the action of $T$ on itself extends to an isometric action on $\mathbb{S}^N$?

Equivalently, $T$ is a geodesic subtorus in a Clifford torus (= an orbit of maximal torus in $\mathrm{O}(n+1)$).

may I ask the "hidden" reason for N being large? I understand that $N=2$ is somehow trivial by realizing $\mathbb P^1$ as a GIT quotient, but why $N$ large?

@L.F.Cavenaghi I am thinking about Gromov's example of flat torus in the sphere with constant normal curvatures (see his "Isometric immersions with ...". arXiv: 2212.06122.). All his examples are minimal + they are geodesic in a Clifford torus, and $N\approx \mathrm{const}\cdot n^2$.

For $n=2$, the answer is 'yes', see Minimal surfaces of constant curvature in $S^n$, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 290 (1985), pp. 259–271.  MR0787964

@RobertBryant Thank you, I am reading it now. Do you think there is a chance to generalize this to $n>2$?

@AntonPetrunin:  I think that there is, especially since you are assuming a compact, flat minimal submanifold.  In my TAMS paper, I assumed only that there was a small piece of a flat minimal surface in the $n$-sphere and the result was that each small piece extends to a complete minimal immersion, and the condition that it close up to a compact surface is even more restrictive.  In the global case, it's already clear that, for a given flat $n$-torus $T$, the space of minimal isometric embeddings into any $S^N$ (up to congruence) is finite dimensional.
